# Custom themes for dojox charting

Tags: javascript, web-applications, dojo, arcgis-js-api, dojox.charting

I am loading a webmap ID and I have 2 charts in a feature_layer popup.
I would like to change the charts themes with something simple like:

```
colors: ["#00ff78", "#7f0043", "#8ecfb0", "#f8acac", "#cc4482"] 
colors: ["#57808f", "#506885", "#4f7878", "#558f7f", "#508567"]
```

Can I code that inside my .html ?
My web app is available on [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/zojuqerilu/1/edit?html,output).
Thank you, Michelle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following CSS which will override the inline style for you chart (SVG) elements.

The selector says, select child x of a decedent of an svg group and change its fill color.

http://jsbin.com/lapefab/edit?html,css,output

```
g > path:nth-of-type(1){
  fill: #FAEBD7;
}

g > path:nth-of-type(2){
  fill: #8A2BE2;
}

g > path:nth-of-type(3){
  fill: #7FFF00;
}
```

I would suggest to assign IDs to you charts so you can have full control on where and how applying your styles. Example:

```
 #yourChart > path:nth-of-type(1){
      fill: #FAEBD7;
    }

 #yourChart > path:nth-of-type(2){
      fill: #8A2BE2;
 }

 #yourChart > path:nth-of-type(3){
      fill: #7FFF00;
 }
```

Comment: Hi @GibboK , seems like this CSS forces all charts to use the same colors. The charts don't have unique chart themes anymore, they are identical.

Comment: @Michelle Hi, you can solve this issue by limitating the scope of your CSS selectors. For example you could assign an ID for each chart and reference it in your CSS, in this case you have total controls of what color is being applied where. Unfortunate I could not found specific ids in your examples so I just briefly mentioned in my answer (new edit).